# Missing parameter type for expanded function with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am getting an error of:

```
Missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
    .mapGroups {
```

and my code is:

```scala
  val customerAccountOutputDS: Dataset[CustomerAccountOutput] = customerDS
    .joinWith(accountDS, customerDS("customerId") === accountDS("customerId"), "left_outer")
    .groupByKey {
      case (customerData, _) => // The second part of the tuple is ignored here
        (customerData.customerId, customerData.forename, customerData.surname)
    }
    .mapGroups {
      case (key, iterator) =>
```

I tried many approaches to it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Does not look like your problem is in using `joinwith`. Its either `groupByKey` or `mapGroups`.

Comment: Would you post the complete code of the `mapGroups`? The error message states the error is on this line. Also what did you try?